# Создание уникальных key и value через цикл в java

Tags: java, циклы, java-hashmap

Как создать уникальные значения `HashMap(key, value)` через цикл?

p.s. Читал, что нужно сделать прибавление порядкового номера

Comment: В каком смысле уникальный? Они и так будут уникальными при добавлении в карту т.е. key = 1, value = "stack"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Как создать уникальные значения `HashMap(key, value)` через цикл?

В цикле добавляете к `key` и `value` номер текущей итерации:

```
HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();

for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
    hashMap.put("key_" + i, "value_" + i);
}
```